# Cannot get one fragment to replace another on a button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently working my way through the Android Developer pages. On runtime I have a fragment that is put into place with a button that say click. What I want to do is have that button simply change the fragment to a different one that I have constructed. Right now, nothing happens when clicked.

```
public class Menu_Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu__fragment, container, false);

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_to_click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Click_Fragment nextFrag = new Click_Fragment();
            FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);

            trans.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
}
```

The button is written into Menu_Fragment's XML and has the corresponding id. My feeling is that is has to do with the `return view;` at the end, but I am unsure about that and wouldn't know how to change that. Any and all help is appreciated. If you can and are willing to just point me in the right direction, that is even better than a hard code solution.

Edit:

In case the issue is with the MainActivity, here is its code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        Menu_Fragment fragment = new Menu_Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to just replace one fragment with another fragment in an activity  with the click of a button?

Comment: @SajibAcharya yes, exactly. Just a simple activity to help me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and straight-forward way to achieve what you want is to provide an `onClick` attribute to the `<Button>` element in the `XML` and since you  have the `button` in the `XML`, I suggest you give it an `onClick` attribute, like `onClick="replaceFragment"` and in your `activity` containing the fragment, simply provide a method `public void replaceFragment(View view){...}`. This method will be called when the button is clicked and must reside within the activity holding the `fragment`. The best practice is to use a `tag` on the fragment while replacing it to avoid recreating similar fragments and instead just replacing them. This is a problem I faced a lot of times. But that is just your choice. Then you can use something like:

```
if(fragment != null) {
            savedFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            if(savedFragment != null) {
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame_id, savedFragment, TAG);
            }
            else {
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame_id, fragment, TAG);
            }

            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

Where `fragment` is your original fragment object like `Fragment fragment = new AnyNewFragmentClass()`.

What this does is it searches whether the `fragment` you are trying to create has already been created, and thus uses it instead of just creating a brand new fragment object. If no fragment is already created, i.e., `savedFragment == null`, then a brand new fragment is created. This is especially useful while maintaining `orientation changes`. Hope this helps. If you are unable to understand any part, do ask. :)

Comment: I immensely appreciate the help. When you say "must reside within the activity holding the `fragment`" would that be my `MainActivity` since that is where they are being displayed? Or do you mean inside where the fragment is defined, i.e. the `Menu_Fragment` class?

Comment: There is always an `activity` that holds a fragment. Whether it be `MainActivity` or `SomeOtherActivity`. The `public void methodName(View)` must be in the `Activity class` where that will hold your fragment. `Menu_Fragment` is not an `Activity`, rather it is the `fragment` itself. ( ... extends Fragment{...}). So, in your case, it should be in the `MainActivity`, but this is necessarily not always true. This can be any activity holding the frament.

Comment: Aslo a major advantage of putting the `button click event` in the `activity` would mean that you are making your `fragment` truly reusable.

Comment: Fully understand about it being in Main or SomeOther now. Thank you again for all of the help. I'll work through this now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Do let me know if you need any help. :)

Comment: I have a few question to ask. First, should this method be in the same scope as the initial fragment? I.e inside the curly braced of the onCreate? Or outside of it but in the public class

I'm also having a little trouble with the idea of savedFragment and TAG. I understand that a tag is a unique identifier, but I do not understand what tag would be used for savedFragment's ID... That makes me unsure about what is being saved the savedFragment variable in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96076/discussion-between-rm3-and-sajib-acharya).

Answer (score 0):

for nested fragments you should use `getChildFragmentManager()`

Edit:

On the other hand, if you need to change the fragment in the main activity, you either need to get main Activities Fragment manager by using

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction...
```

or make a public method in the main Activity, to change the fragment and call it from the Child Fragment by using

```
getActivity().ChangeFragment();
```

and in the main Activity

```
public void ChangeFragment(){
            FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            trans.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);

            trans.commit();
}
```

Comment: The answer should be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: it's pretty obvious, for nested fragments instead of using `            FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
` you should use `            FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
`

Comment: To be fair, I did say to only point me in the right direction :) I take it that would be used in like this: `FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` ...unfortunately that does not appear to be the only issue. After you recommended change, the app stops running when the button is clicked

Comment: Your edit is more along the lines of what I am doing. Nested fragments seem to be...well...nested, so one inside the other. I simply want to replace one with another.

Comment: OP is not dealing with nested fragments here. A simple replacement of fragments is what he wants.

Comment: well the question before the edit, suggested it was a matter of nested fragments, although after the edit I also edited my answer and added the part about changing the main fragment, anyway, I'm glad @RM3's problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Use following approach to avoid your problems:

```
String TAG="fragmentFirst";

  // to replace
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment, TAG)
            .commit();

    //find by tag as needs    
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion now, I'll be sure to let you know how it goes